# How to lookup all rows in an SQL database that have a certain Boolean column value of true in asp.net?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I have a table that has two boolean columns: isActive and isAcceptingParticipants.

I want to get all the rows in which both of these are true.

I have included the Models file below and a partial implementation of the services that I would like.

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace ProjectTracker.Models
{
    public class Project
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int CountParticipants { get; set; }
        public int CountActiveParticipants { get; set; }
        public Boolean isActive { get; set; }
        public Boolean isAcceptingParticipants { get; set; }
        public int WhoseTurn { get; set; }
    }
}
```

this is the services module where I want to implement GetInProgress which will return all rows that have isActive and isAccepting participants as both being true.

```
using ProjectTracker.Models;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;
using ProjectTracker.Data;
using System.Linq;

namespace ProjectTracker.Services
{

    public interface IProjectData
    {
        IEnumerable<Project> GetAcceptingParticipants();
        IEnumerable<Project> GetInProgress();
        Project ParticipatingIn(int id); //Pass userId to this, returns the project that the user is part of
        Project Add(Project newProject);
        Project Get(int id);
        void Delete(int id);
        void Commit();
    }

    public class SqlProjectData : IProjectData
    {
        private ApplicationDbContext _context;

        public SqlProjectData(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public Project Add(Project newProject)
        {
            _context.Add(newProject);
            Commit();
            return newProject;
        }

        public void Commit()
        {
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }

        public void Delete(int id)
        {
            var toBeDeleted = Get(id);
            if (toBeDeleted == null) return;
            _context.Remove<Project>(toBeDeleted);
        }

        public Project Get(int id)
        {
            return _context.Project.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Id == id);
        }

        public IEnumerable<Project> GetAcceptingParticipants()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public IEnumerable<Project> GetInProgress()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public Project ParticipatingIn(int id)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use LINQ:

```
return _context.Project.Where(r => r.isActive && r.isAcceptingParticipants);
```

Comment: Need to add .ToList() as method return is Enumerable

Comment: @ISHIDA Oh no his method returns an `IEnumerable<Project>` so you don't need that.

Comment: This was what I was looking for, TY!

Answer (score 0):

```
public IEnumerable<Project> GetInProgress()
{
    return _context.Project.Where(r => r.isActive && r.isAcceptingParticipants).ToList();
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.